# Typescript: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit"' in Date::toLocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have recently been alerted to an "error" by Visual Studio Code in the following snippet:

```
someDateObject.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', Travel.dateOptions));
someDateObject.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', Travel.dateOptions));
```

Where Travel.dateOptions is defined as such:

```
public static dateOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
```

This has been working fine for the better part of the last 2 years, but upon opening the class inside VSC recently, it displayed following error for `Travel.dateOptions`:

```
Argument of type '{ year: string; month: string; day: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
Types of property 'year' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"numeric" | "2-digit"'. ts(2345)
```

I am dead confused as to why. Is this possibly a bug with VSC? The code seems to work fine (and has worked fine the entire time) once compiled - and according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for Date::toLocaleDateString() what I'm doing here seems perfectly valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you initialize a class property with a literal such as `public foo = { bar: 'a' }`, its type becomes `{ bar: string }`, even if you declare it as `readonly`. TypeScript on purpose doesn't make the type too strict (`{ bar: 'a' }`).

Method `toLocaleDateString` accepts an object whose key `year` must be of type `'numeric'` or `'2-digit'`, but yours is of type `string`.

To make the type of the initialized object more specific, use `as const`:

```
public static dateOptions = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' } as const;
```

Answer (score 36):

I've just hit the same problem, rather than redeclare the const as const (which feels like a code smell) I forced the variable type:

```
  formatDT(sourceDate: Date) {
    const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = { month: "long", day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: "2-digit" };
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", options).format(new Date(sourceDate));
  }
```

Comment: This makes more sense, it worked for me.

Comment: Why do you think `as const` is a code smell? You're also basically using `as Int.DateTimeFormatOptions`, just with a different syntax.

Comment:  very OOP  

Answer (score 21):

Following your code example you must explicitly declare the `DateTimeFormatOptions` data type for `dateOptions`

```js
const dateOptions: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
};

export const Travel = { dateOptions };

const someDateObject = new Date();

console.log(someDateObject.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', Travel.dateOptions));
```

Answer (score 7):

Include `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` for the declaration.

```
const options :Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = { 
    year: 'numeric', 
    month: '2-digit', 
    day: 'numeric', 
    hour: '2-digit', 
    minute: '2-digit', 
    hour12: false 
};
```

Comment: Please note that the same approach has been shown by Matias before.